# How to do I calculate the hazard rate accurately in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability-density

I need to calculate the hazard-rate, PDF/(1-CDF), of a Rayleigh function over `x`.

```
x = 0:0.001:2.5;
HR = pdf('rayl',x,sqrt(1/18))./(1-cdf('rayl',x,sqrt(1/18)));
plot(x,HR)
```

Here the plot becomes funny at approximately `x = 2`. How can I improve accuracy of the HR?

Comment: To those marking this as unclear, what is unclear? Just the definition of "funny"? I think that it's fairly clear that this is a numerical issue.

Comment: The description "funny" certainly isn't helpful, and to figure out exactly in what way it's "funny" requires running the Matlab code (which itself requires access to the Statistics toolbox in addition to Matlab).  You're cutting down who can and who is willing to figure out what the real question is because of the way this is written.  Questions are supposed to be self-contained to avoid this and to provide archive value. As it turns out, this question has nothing to do with Matlab, so a better written question would have potential value to many users.

Comment: @ Brick: I see your points. This is my first post here. I'll try to be more specific next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into numerical issues, specifically [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). Try plotting just the denominator of your hazard rate function, [the complementary CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Complementary_cumulative_distribution_function_.28tail_distribution.29), on a [`semilogy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html) plot:

```
x = 0:0.001:2.5;
semilogy(x,1-cdf('rayl',x,sqrt(1/18)))
```

[image: Complementary Rayleigh CDF plot]

As you can see, there are issues a bit before x = 2 when the denominator is approximately [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon), [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html). This is when `cdf('rayl',x,sqrt(1/18))` is about 1.

Luckily, Matlab provides a way around this with an option that calculates the complementary CDF, or tail probability of the CDF, directly via the `'upper'` option for [`cdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdf.html):

```
x = 0:0.001:2.5;
HR = pdf('rayl',x,sqrt(1/18))./cdf('rayl',x,sqrt(1/18),'upper');
plot(x,HR)
```

which now returns a straight line with a slope of 18, as expected. The [`raylcdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/raylcdf.html) function also supports this option.